# Why values of array are null in this case?

Tags: java

I am dynamically creating SQL and setting values into them as shown

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
        String vendor_brand_id = "3000";
         String reqstr = "popcorn";
         String category_id = "11";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

            String fixedvalues[] = new String[10];
            String inputStr[] = reqstr.split("@");
            for(int j=0;j<inputStr.length;j++)
            {
                fixedvalues[j]=inputStr[j];
                System.out.println("jii"+fixedvalues[j]);

            }
            Connection dbConnection = null;
            String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE category_dev SET T1 = ? , T2 = ? , T3 = ? , T4 = ? , T5 = ? , T6=? , T7= ? , T8 = ? , T9 = ? , T10 = ? , vendor_brand_id = ? where category_id = ?";
            dbConnection = DBConnection.getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);
            for (int i = 0; i < fixedvalues.length; i++) {
                preparedStatement.setString(1, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(3, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(4, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(5, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(6, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(7, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(8, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(9, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(10, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(11, vendor_brand_id);
                preparedStatement.setString(12, category_id);
            }

            System.out.println(preparedStatement);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But the issue i am facing here is that the values are being set as null

could anybody please let me know why

The sql that is being formed here is

```
UPDATE category_dev SET T1 = null , T2 = null , T3 = null , T4 = null , T5 = null , T6=null , T7= null , T8 = null , T9 = null , T10 = null , vendor_brand_id = '3000' where category_id = '11'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're only populating `fixedValues` with as many values as are in `inputStr`:

```
for(int j=0;j<inputStr.length;j++)
{
    fixedvalues[j]=inputStr[j];
    System.out.println("jii"+fixedvalues[j]);
}
```

You're then running over all 10 elements of `fixedValues` and for each value, setting *all* the first to parameters in your prepared statement to that value. This means if `inputStr` has less than 10 values, at the end of your loop all the prepared statement parameters will be null.

I strongly suspect that your prepared statement loop preparation should actually be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fixedvalues.length; i++) {
    preparedStatement.setString(i, fixedvalues[i]);
}
preparedStatement.setString(11, vendor_brand_id);
preparedStatement.setString(12, category_id);
```

So each prepared statement parameter ends up with a different value from `fixedvalues`. Surely that's what you really intended...

Comment: Ya i am only initializing the fixedvalues with values of inputStr or else it will be null know.

Comment: @Kiran: I've already shown you how to fix it. Did you read my whole answer?

Comment: Thank you , i just fixed this , so kind of you .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you realize that in this loop all you are doing is setting all your variables to the same thing until you get to the last of your `fixedvalues`. The end result will be that you set all fields to `fixedvalues[fixedvalues.length - 1]`

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);
            for (int i = 0; i < fixedvalues.length; i++) {
                preparedStatement.setString(1, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(3, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(4, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(5, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(6, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(7, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(8, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(9, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(10, fixedvalues[i]);
                preparedStatement.setString(11, vendor_brand_id);
                preparedStatement.setString(12, category_id);
            }
```